# How to set a text at the left of a RadioButton without using TextView?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

is there anyway to set the text of `radio button` to the left of it?
I checked the properties of `radio button` elemnt in the `xml files` and i did not find such a property?

So, if such property is not available how to write a text at the left of a `radio button`, given that my  `radio buttons` are childs of `radioGroup` and i do not want to use `textView` elemnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding attributes `android:button="@null"` and `android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"` to each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your RadioButton :

```
 android:button="@null"
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
 android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```